# Storing different datatypes in one column to reduce table count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, azure-sql-database

I am currently working on a project where I am recreating a MS SQL Server database in Azure SQL database. I have been given the current schema (although not with the actual column data type) and I came across this:

```
Question (QuestionID, QuestionDescription, UnitOfMeasure, SQLDataType)
QuestionAnswer (QuestionID, AnswerID, Answer, SQLDataType, UnitOfMeasure)
```

So, the database contains a variety of questions which each are answered/measured with different types of data (int, text, date, etc,..) and ALL answers are stored together with a column identifying the data type used in the "Answer" column.

I would like to know if this is a common practice and how this can be implemented? (Multiple types of data in one column). An alternative would obviously be to keep all questions together but seperate out the various answers into different tables, but I can see how that becomes cumbersome with 30+ different questions.

Comment: I have seen this done before. But putting the data type and scale (UnitOfMeasure) in the answer table is not a good practice. It shouldn't be replicated to the answer, it is already part of the question.

Comment: Any reason why not use sql_variant?

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?FearOfAddingTables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pattern that we use in production for the same type of problem. Yes, it works - you just have to make sure that each `Answer` can actually be cast to the given `SQLDataType`. We do this at insert/update time.

Comment: Okay. What would the default Answer datatype for the table creation? 
Does the SQLDataType column just store the string name of the data type? (I.e. 'int', 'varchar()', 'date')

Comment: Yep. We use `nvarchar` for both.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use sql_variant (the documentation is not clear about Azure).

A big advantage is that you don't have to maintain any metadata about the values.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx

---

```
create table t (val sql_variant);

insert into t (val) values (123);
insert into t (val) values (4.5);
insert into t (val) values ('Hello');
insert into t (val) values (N'שלום');
insert into t (val) values (GETDATE());
insert into t (val) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into t (val) values (newid());

select      t.val   
           ,sql_variant_property(t.val, 'BaseType')
           ,sql_variant_property(t.val, 'Precision')
           ,sql_variant_property(t.val, 'Scale')
           ,sql_variant_property(t.val, 'TotalBytes')
           ,sql_variant_property(t.val, 'Collation')
           ,sql_variant_property(t.val, 'MaxLength')

from        t
;
```

---

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦════╦═══╦════╦══════════════════════════════╦══════╗
║                 123                  ║       int        ║ 10 ║ 0 ║ 6  ║             NULL             ║  4   ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════╬═══╬════╬══════════════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 4.5                                  ║ numeric          ║  2 ║ 1 ║  9 ║ NULL                         ║    5 ║
║ Hello                                ║ varchar          ║  0 ║ 0 ║ 13 ║ SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ║ 8000 ║
║ שלום                                ║ nvarchar         ║  0 ║ 0 ║ 16 ║ SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ║ 8000 ║
║ 2016-10-27 21:08:58.027              ║ datetime         ║ 23 ║ 3 ║ 10 ║ NULL                         ║    8 ║
║ 2016-10-27 21:08:58.030              ║ datetime         ║ 23 ║ 3 ║ 10 ║ NULL                         ║    8 ║
║ E0FBA251-8DC2-4F88-9D23-1FB354932AE5 ║ uniqueidentifier ║  0 ║ 0 ║ 18 ║ NULL                         ║   16 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩════╩═══╩════╩══════════════════════════════╩══════╝
```